# Graph call "/me/friends" doesn't contain names if called from a testuser

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When I log into Facebook with my account and call the Graph API with **/me/friends** it returns an array like this:

```
[
    {id: "6868...", name: "John Smith"}, 
    {id: "7531...", name: "Diane Smith"}, 
    ...
]
```

But if I'm logged in with a Facebook [testuser](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/) and do the same call I get an array like this:

```
[
    {id: "100002927..."}, 
    {id: "100003151..."}, 
    ...
]
```

So I'm missing the **name** property.

Bug? Or did I some mistake? I'm using the JS SDK, but I think that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that there is no possibility to archive that - it's a bug in the Facebook API apparently.

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
facebook->api("me/friends&fields=name");
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work (it works if I'm logged in with my personal account but with the facebook testuser I still get the id information only, nothing more)